# In Java 8, How combine two different collection into one with one matching field?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to combine 2 different data type collection using one matching field.

```
List<Foo> foos...
List<Bar> bars... 

public class Foo {
    Integer fooId;
    Integer name;
    Integer description;
    Integer sent; //this should be coming from Bar
    Integer received; //this should be coming from Bar
}

public class Bar {
    Integer barId;
    Integer fooId; //combine into Foo using this field
    Integer sent;
    Integer received;
}
```

I would like to get the data from Bar then put them in Foo using fooId. Both collection has unique data by fooId.

Comment: By combine, do you mean you want to sum the two fields from `Bar` objects that have the same `fooId`, and store the resulting sums in the fields of the `Foo` object?

Comment: They have unique data by foodId.

Comment: That's a weird data model. Why does `Bar` need it's own id, if there can only be one per `fooId`? That would make `Bar` a sub-table of `Foo` and it should just use the `fooId` as it's own id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't think anybody understands what you are trying to do. So no, it's definitely not clear enough. If you want an answer in order to solve your probllem, I would suggest to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To make code more beautiful, you can take a look at this below :)

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
List<Bar> bars = ...

// convert list bars to the map
Map<Integer, Bar> map4Bar = bars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Bar::getFooId, Function.identity()));

// combine the some bar into the foo
foos.forEach(foo -> foo.modifyByBar(map4Bar.get(foo.getFooId())));
```

And in the `Foo` class there should be a new method named convert, just like this:

```
public Foo modifyByBar(Bar bar){
     if(bar != null){
        this.sent = bar.sent;
        this.received = bar.received;
     }
     return this;        
}
```

Is my code more beautiful? maybe... not, haha~~~^_^

Comment: Thanks @Holger, you are right, the second opertion looks not beatiful at all, haha. And I have modified it. As for the `convert` method, how about the new name `modifyByBar`?

Comment: Not the best name in the world, but sufficient. Mind the required semicolon at the end of the `forEach` statement.

Comment: Wow, @Holger, you are so careful. I modify it directly in the text, so without any IDE, I had made such a silly mistake. Thanks again! : )

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over every combination of elements and checking whether `foos[index].fooId == bars[index2].fooId`. Something like this:

```
for(Foo foo : foos){
   for(Bar bar : bars){
      if(foo.fooId == bar.fooId){
         foo.sent = bar.sent;
         foo.received = bar.received;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not java 8

Comment: You're right. The line `foos[index].fooId == bars[index2].fooId` is invalid syntax. The nested for loops are the actual solution and should still work in Java.

Comment: That's the slow way to go, and what happens if two `Bar` objects have the same `fooId`? You'd expect `fooId` to be unique for `Foo` objects, and `barId` to be unique for `Bar` objects, but you wouldn't normally expect `fooId` to be unique for `Bar` objects.

Comment: As given above, the foo will just be overwritten with the data from whichever bar occurs later in the list. Depending on the meaning of sent and received, you could change the collision rule to addition (e.g. `foo.sent += bar.sent;`) .

Comment: Since `fooId` fields are `Integer`, they should not be compared with `==`.  Use `foo.fooId.equals(bar.fooId)` or `Objects.equals(foo.fooId, bar.fooId)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<Foo> fooStream = foos.stream();
fooStream.forEach(f ->
    bars.stream().filter(b -> b.fooId.equals(f.fooId)).findFirst().ifPresent(b -> {
      f.sent = b.sent;
      f.received = b.received;
    })
);
```

Comment: I don't think it's simpler than just iterating the Lists. You should do some research into java ORMapping library, then you'll know how to design a  better Foo/Bar class.

Comment: Those that work ? Once the barStream is filtered with the first fooId ... how fo you reuse it with another fooId ??

Comment: @Pras. My mistake. The bar Stream can't be reused. So I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a classic lookup problem, so I suggest you handle it as a lookup:

```
    List<Foo> foos = ...
    List<Bar> bars = ...

    Map<Integer, Bar> barLookup = bars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(bar -> bar.fooId, bar -> bar));
    foos.forEach(foo -> {
        Bar bar = barLookup.get(foo.fooId);
        foo.sent = bar.sent;
        // etc
    });
```